# Downloaded image does not have border

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using fabricjs canvas for designing. Using java script to downloading image file. but after downloading can't see image border.

Code sample:

```
<canvas id="c" runat="server" style="border:2px solid black;" ></canvas>
<img alt="" src="" id="finalImge" runat="server" style="border:2px solid black;" />
function DownloadDesign()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c').fabric;
    var img = document.getElementById('finalImge');
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var a = $("<a>").attr("href", img.src).attr("download", "Design.png").appendTo("body");
    a[0].click();
    a.remove();
}
```

Comment: apply border to canvas then try downloading
example: canvas .style.border = '1px solid #000';

Comment: i tried that also.. but after downloading image has no border..

Comment: @pareshm.. i got this error after adding border to canvas. Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'border' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/yvqmp1so/

```
var boundingBox = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: "transparent",
  width: 590,
  height: 590,
  stroke: "red",
  strokeWidth: 10,
  selectable: false
});
canvas.add(boundingBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's normal

your border is not in canvas

if you want the border, you must add border in canvas

Comment: @neopheus..but how can i do it? I'm using fabricjs